# linebreak in title when the title is before the beginning of the document

Tags: line-breaking, titles

Pretty simple question I think but I cant seem to find the answer anywhere: How can i line break the title inside the \title{} command if this title command is before the \begin{document} command (because of a using a particular template?

So \title{first part \ second part} doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Can you add a small but compilable test document which allows us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: To break a line, use a *double* backslash. With standard classes, it can be used within `\title` without problem (the fact it's before `\begin{document}` doesn't matter)